# Multiply two fields in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Is there any option for multiply two fields in LINQ

```
public class details
{
 public int qty { get; set; }
 public decimal unitprice{ get; set; }
 public decimal total{ get; set; }
}

select new details
{
 qty =x.qty ,
 unitprice= x.unitprice,
 total= x.qty*x.unitprice,
}
```

If not pls give any proper code

Comment: You did correct only. What's the issue ?

Comment: Check null or 0 value before multiply. like **total = (x.qty != 0 ? x.qty : 1) *(x.unitprice != 0 ? x.unitprice : 1)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a `Select()` clause:

```
someLinqQuery.Select(detailsObject => new details
{
    qty = detailsObject.qty,
    unitprice = detailsObject.unitprice,
    total = detailsObject.qty * detailsObject.unitprice
}
```

But it looks like you need a get only property like this:

```
public class details
{
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public decimal unitprice { get; set; }
    public decimal total =>  qty * unitprice;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using the `let` keyword in the linq query syntax

```
var result = from x in items
             let total = ((decimal)x.qty) * x.unitprice
             select new details {
                 qty = x.qty ,
                 unitprice = x.unitprice,
                 total = total
             };
```